Transforming columns in pandas dataframe into quartiles
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like
columnA   columnB           
3         -1                    
73        2                   
2         13                    
-2        24                    
4         1                   
8         2                   
23        3                    
13        5                    
2         2                    
0         3                    
1         4                   
2         1                    
7         2                    
2         1                    
2         2                    
5         3                    

For columnA that range is 73-(-2)=75 and hence the four quartiles are given by 1st quartile = [-2 - 16.75], 2nd quartile = [16.75, 35.5], 3rd quartile = [35.5, 54.25], 4th quartile = [54.25, 73] and I want to transform the columns by labelling which quartile the element is in. So for example, columnA would become
columnA   columnB           
1         -1                    
4         2                   
1         13                    
1         24                    
1         1                   
1         2                   
2         3                    
1         5                    
1         2                    
1         3                    
1         4                   
1         1                    
1         2                    
1         1                    
1         2                    
1         3                    

I think it has something to do with .transform but I am not how how to partition it into quartiles.

use pd.cut

@PandaKim that solves my problem instantly, many thanks!
